# Automatically navigate to https url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I hosted my ASP.NET MVC site based on SSL authentication as https://example.com.
If user navigate to http://example.com it should automatically redirect to https://example.com.
Is there any possible way to do this.

Comment: Can anybody help how to do the same thing in JSP servlet page?

Answer (score 1):

Install the URL Rewrite module and add the below to your web.config in `system.webserver`:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```